# Adding an ID to the URL manager

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I've been having a hard time understanding Yii's URL Manager. I have a URL that goes to this `createurl('site/category',array('id'=$id))` and it doesn't work:

> site/category/1?cat=Accessories

When I go here to this URL, it works:

> /site/category/id/1?cat=Accessories

If I'm supposed to custom-write it, does it go under the components? If so, what would be the next step? I'm just not understanding this, unfortunately.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'showScriptName'=>false,
  'appendParams' => true,
  'rules'=>array(
    'site/category/id/<id:\d+>/<item:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This

`createurl('site/category',array('id'=$id))`

Should be:

`createurl('site/category',array('id' => $id))`

What URL are you trying to generate?

Your rule says will generate

site/category/id/{number goes here}/itemInLetters

For yours to work you need to pass create it with the item parameter:

`createurl('site/category',array('id' => $id, 'item' => 'MyItem'))`

Comment: yes that was a typo in here. And yes, there is another `'item' => 'MyItem'` i have something like `'site/category',array('id'=>1,'cat'=>"blah")` but no matter what i change in the url rules it just goes to `site/category/1?cat=blah`

Answer (score 0):

just change your rule like this:

```
'rules'=>array(
    'site/category/<id:\d+>/<item:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', // removed id
    .
    .
    .
  ),
```